# How to import a PostCSS variable into another PostCSS file with absolute url in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[image]

I have `src` folder in the root directory, and I wanna import a variable in `common/colors.css` into `components/header.module.css`.

So in `header.module.css`, I tried `@value green from "/common/colors.css";` but it didn't work.

With relative url instead, `@value green from "../../common/colors.css";` worked.

How can I achieve this with absolute url?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer you're looking for but one option would be to move your `colors.css` into the `public` directory.

Then you could `@value green from "/common/colors.css"`